# Error con atributo serial en particiones postgres

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql

Tengo una tabla de donde heredan otras tres y tengo un trigger en la tabla padre que se encarga de distribuir lo que inserto a las tablas hijas. En ellas esta el atributo traID, que es de tipo serial.

```
create table "Trabajador"(
    "traID" serial primary key,
    "traNombre" character(30),
    "traApellidos" character(50),
    "traNIF" character(10));

create table "Trabajador_AJ"(
    check ("traApellidos" SIMILAR TO '[A-J]%')
) inherits ("Trabajador");

create table "Trabajador_KQ"(
    check ("traApellidos" SIMILAR TO '[K-Q]%')
) inherits ("Trabajador");

create table "Trabajador_RZ"(
    check ("traApellidos" SIMILAR TO '[R-Z]%')
) inherits ("Trabajador");

create or replace function "trabajador_insertar"()
return trigger as $$
begin
    if( new."traApellidos" similar to '[A-J]%') then 
        insert into "Trabajador_AJ"("traNombre","traApellidos","traNIF") values 
        (new."traNombre",new."traApellidos",new."traNIF");
    elsif(new."traApellidos" similar to '[K-Q]%') then
        insert into "Trabajador_KQ"("traNombre","traApellidos","traNIF") values 
        (new."traNombre",new."traApellidos",new."traNIF");
    elsif (new."traApellidos" similar to '[R-Z]%') then
        insert into "Trabajador_RZ"("traNombre","traApellidos","traNIF") values 
        (new."traNombre",new."traApellidos",new."traNIF");
    ELSE
    end if;
    return null;
end;
$$
```

El problema esta en que cuando hago consulta a las tablas, traID se muestra de esta manera:

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 ...
```

En vez de como debe ser:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
```

El atributo serial pasa de los números impares. ¿Cómo soluciono esto? ¡De antemano, gracias!

Comment: Parece que la tabla tiene un incremento de dos en dos en la secuencia, puedes determinar cómo se llama la secuencia haciendo algo como esto: `pg_get_serial_sequence('nombre_de_tu_tabla','nombre_de_la_columna_serial')` y luego puedes cambiar la secuencia así: `ALTER SEQUENCE tabla_columna_seq RESTART WITH 1`  donde `tabla` sería el nombre de la tabla, `id` el nombre de la columna serial y `seq` el nombre de la secuencia de esa columna. Si quieres renumerar todo (OJO, no lo hagas si los id ya están relacionados): `ALTER SEQUENCE seq RESTART WITH 1; UPDATE tabla SET id=nextval('seq');`

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me ha funcionado. Solo que he tenido que ser mas especifico en `update "Trabajador" set "traID"=nextval('traID_seq'::regclass);`.